# how to get data from facebook graph api in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, facebook, jquery-plugins, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get json data using facebook graph api through jquery. I am using the code below. I am trying to get json data using $.getJSON function but it displays this error in firebug

```
NetworkError: 400 Bad Request - https://graph.facebook.com/me/home?access_token=mytoken
```

here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"> 
     </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script/script.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function(){
            //$('fb').fbWall();
            var url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/home?access_token=mytoken";
            var html = "<ul>";
            $.getJSON(url, function(json){
                //console.log(json);
                $.each(json.data, function(i,fb){
                    html += "<li>" + fb.id + "</li>";
                });
            });
            html += "</ul>";

            $('.fb').animate({opacity: 0}, 500, function() {
                $('.fb').html(html);
            });
            $('.fb').animate({opacity:1}, 500);
        });
    </script>
    <!-- <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" /> -->
    <style>
        .fb {
            width: 400px; height: 400px;
            border:1px solid red;
        }
    </style>
    <title>title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="fb">

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

where am I making mistake?

Comment: by posting your access token you gave everyone permission to see your account details

Comment: Are you sure that's the right access token?

Comment: yes it is correct access token. Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the URL you posted directly, it is returning the error:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#606) Queries for multiple source_ids require a non-zero viewer that has granted read_stream permission",
      "type": "OAuthException"
   }
}
```

It means you need to prompt for read_stream permission to read the users feed.

Comment: Ok guys, I changed my token to this format "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|JwbAtDcinTgJPpO3I_pcNOdd5gs".

Now when I use this link "https://graph.facebook.com/ID/feed?access_token=170270366392401|JwbAtDcinTgJPpO3I_pcNOdd5gs" in the browser it does show all feeds but when I use it in my code it does not show any thing. In firebug it says
 
    GET https://graph.facebook.com/xafarsaleem/feed?access_token=170270366392401|JwbAtDcinTgJPpO3I_pcNOdd5gs
 
    200 OK

But it does not get any json data.